# Why am I getting this error? How to solve this error?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have tried to install synaptic package manager and in the terminal it is showing me some error.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dpkg/apt is running somewhere else possibly in another terminal window.  Or you might have accidentally closed the terminal window where dpkg/apt was working.  If your sure dpkg/apt aren't running somewhere else, you could delete the lock file.